# Grails error while run-app

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am getting below error while trying to start the grails app.

```
 Loading Grails 2.2.1
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application....
| Compiling 2 source files.
| **Error Error packaging application: 
java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.String 
(Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)**
```

I started getting this error after I installed easygrid plugin and tried to start the app.

A quick search on this error gave [this result](https://github.com/tudor-malene/Easygrid/issues/6).

Any suggestions on how to resolve this error.

I am using GGTS as the IDE and Grails 2.2.1 with Groovy 2.0.

Comment: Scroll down to the bottom of the github issue where [GRAILS #9900](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9900) bug is referred. It is fixed for version Grails 2.2.2. Consider an upgrade.

Comment: @dmahapatro Thanks for the reply. I gone through that link but could not find that it is fixed in the 2.2.2 release. I went through the release notes for Grails 2.2.2 and I see that the bug is fixed. I will give it a try and update here.

Comment: I upgraded to 2.2.3 and it worked. Thanks for pointing it out @dmahapatro